# Getting error while tryng to add geometry (polygon z) to table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I'm trying to insert a row to `postgres` (`postgis`) table and getting error.

My table (`geo_table`) properties:

```
id serial PRIMARY_KEY,
name text,
geometry geometry,
in_use boolean,
related text
```

I'm trying to add data:

```
INSERT into geo_table (name, geometry, in_use) VALUES ('tb2', POLYGON Z ((SOME NUMBERS)), FALSE);
```

I'm getting the following error:

> syntax error at or near "Z" ...(name, geometry, in_use) VALUES ('tb2',
> POLYGON Z ((

what is the error ? and how can I add data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to include between single quotes `'`, it should work.

```
INSERT into geo_table (name, geometry, in_use) 
VALUES ('tb2', 'POLYGON Z (SOME NUMBERS)', FALSE);
```